# Return maximum for each row based on multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am attempting to return a value based on three criteria for each row.

Based on the attached picture, I want to return the price of the max value when the color is the same and the group is the same.

For example, for color = Red and group = A, the max value is 7, so the max price column should be 50 any time color = Red and group = A.

[image: Example Data]

If this wasn't clear please let me know and I'll do my best to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that there is only one unique combination of Color, Group and Max. In other words there would only be one max for a given Color/Group combination. With this assumption we can use `SUMIFS()` to add them, since there's only the one.

The trick is figuring out which row has the largest value in the Max column for the Color/Group combination. There are two options depending which version of Excel you're using:

Excel 2016: `=SUMIFS(Prices,Colors,A2,Groups,B2,Maxes,MAXIFS(Maxes,Colors,A2,Groups,B2))`

Older versions: {`=SUMIFS(Prices,Colors,A2,Groups,B2,Maxes,MAX(IF(Colors&Groups=A2&B2,Maxes)))`} (entered as an array formula--press Ctrl-Shift-Enter)

I've made named ranges to keep the formula readable ('Colors' is A2:A17, etc.).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Create Table below the data, comprises `Color, 
   Group, Max & Max Price`.
2. Write this Formula to get `Group Maximum` in 
   Cell `B20` & fill down:

   ```
     =SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(($A$2:$A$17=$A20)*($B$2:$B$17=$B20)*($C$2:$C$17),1))
   ```
3. Write this Formula to get `Max Price` in Cell 
   `C20` & fill down.

   ```
     =SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(($A$2:$A$17=$A20)*($B$2:$B$17=$B20)*($C$2:$C$17=$C20)*($D$2:$D$17),1))
   ```
4. *Just to compare the original values with the      results below, I've applied Red color to cell     values, which is an optional.*
5. *Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple (relatively anyways) Index/Match using `MAXIFS()`.  First, for simplicity in reading the formula, I created named ranges for the different groups.  Simply take rows 2:[lastRow] of your data and give it a name matching the header.

(Enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd> and drag down):

```
=INDEX(Price,MATCH($A2&$B2&MAXIFS(Max,color,A2,group,B2),color&group&Max,0))
```

[image]

[image]